# Autocomplete не отображается в браузере

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Во View есть input :

```
<input type="text" name="name" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Company")' />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
    });
});
```

Строки подключения из layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/all.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

В инпут автоматически должны подставить из бд список. Сервер отдает инфу. Но инпут странно себя ведет. Список не отображается и видно пустоту.  Как поправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй добавить в `input` `autocomplete="on"`

Comment: @Nikita пробовал, не помогает

Comment: если не сможешь решить свою проблему, попробуй этот фреймовик https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неподдерживаемый формат возвращаемого массива данных из источника `source`.
Плагин *jQuery UI Autocomplete* ожидает получить:

- массив строк: `["one", "two", "etc"]`
- массив объектов с одним из или обоими свойствами `value` и `label`,
  `[{"label": "one", value: "one"}, {"value": "two"}, {"label": "etc"}]`

Так как в ваших объектах нет свойств `label` и `value`, плагин отрабатывает некорректно. Он создает пункты меню, но не отображает их названия.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно:

#### Вариант 1

Вернуть корректные данные от бэкенда. Например,

```
var models = persons.Select(x => new { value = x.Id, label = x.Name });
```

#### Вариант 2

Модифицировать полученные данные на стороне клиента в обработчике события [`response`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response)

```
target.autocomplete({
  source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") 

  response: function(event, ui) {
    ui.content.forEach(function (item) {
      item.value = item.Id;
      item.label = item.Name;
    })
  }
});
```

#### Вариант 3

Переопределить функцию плагина [`_renderItem( ul, item )`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem), отвечающую за рендеринг элемента выпадающего списка:

```
target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
target.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $("<li>")
           .append($("<div>").text(item.Name))
           .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: Да, помогло. Только не  пойму почему не текст подставляется в поле а число(id)?

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев каким вариантом воспользовались? и о каком поле идет речь?

Comment: 2 вариантом воспользовался